# VIM open c++ header file in vertical split by combining three commands

Tags: vim, ctags

I have indexed my c++ codebase with ctags, I can open a header file as follows:

```
:tag myfile.h
```

(It doesn't matter where myfile.h is located, as long as it is inside the indexed codebase it will open correctly in vim)

When I'm editing a c++ file, I can get the header filename as follows:

```
:e%<.h
```

e.g. when editing myfile.cpp, executing this command will display myfile.h on the command line.

A file can be opened in vertical split, by issuing:

```
:vs <myfile>
```

**Now what I want to accomplish, is to have 1 command or function which I can use to open a header file of the corresponding c++ file that I'm currently editing in vertical split. Hence basically I want to combine the 3 above commands as if I would be doing a Unix pipe, e.g.:**

```
:vs tag | e%<.h

" :vs     to open file in vertical split
" :tag    to find tag
" :e%<.h  to get header filename
```

Obviously the Unix pipe doesn't work on vim, alternatively I've tried to write a function at which I assign the result of a command to a variable, e.g.

```
headerFileName = :e%<.h
```

Which apparently is not the correct way of doing this, I'm a bit lost here so I hope somebody can provide some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist several plugins that already do this (without needing a ctags database BTW).

For instance, with *alternate* (aka a.vim), you just have to type `:VS` from the header file or the source file to open the other one in a vertically split window.

Note that *alternate* have an option to tell where to find the other file (same directory, `substitute` on directory name, ...)

Otherwise, I suspect you are looking for `expand()` and `:exe`. If you write a function it may be

```
function! s:whatever() abort
    let crt = expand('%:t:r')
    vnew
    exe 'tag '.crt.'.h'
endfunction
command! whatever call s:whatever()
```